# Negative margin breaks float

Tags: html, css, css-float, margin

While I was working on something, I noticed a very strange behaviour which I couldn't explain. The only difference between the two scenarios is that the `<i>`s in the second example have `margin-top` set to `-10px` instead of `-9px`. I use the negative margin to shift all of the boxes top with the same ammount.

```css
main, aside {
  width: 100%;
  padding: 20px 0 10px;
  margin-bottom: 10px;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: lightblue;
}

main i, aside i {
  float: left;
  display: block;
  width: 10px;
  height: 10px;
  margin: -9px 0 0 5px;
  background: orange;
}

aside i {
  margin-top: -10px;
}
```

```html
<main>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
</main>
<aside>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
  <i></i>
</aside>
```

With only that tiny little change of the top margin they stack on top of each other instead of next to each other. I can't understand what is causing it. I confirmed this behaviour with Gecko and WebKit based browsers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'll try an explanation (or better called, an interpretation) for the abnormal scenario. I can't be sure that what I interpret is correct because the specs have a lot of rules and also the browser implementation may not be completely according to the specs.

The first float box is positioned left most in the parent and shifted 10px upwards (because of the -10px margin). When the rendering searches for a position for the second box, it starts looking at height 0 of the parent and goes from right to left until it encounters another float, but it doesn't because the first float was shifted completely out of the parent, so it goes all the way to the left. If it happens like this, the 9 float positioning rules are still respected (more or less, again it depends on how the developers interpreted some things).

Also consider this disclaimer from the margins section:

> Negative values for margin properties are allowed, but there may be
>   implementation-specific limits.

You should understand from it that negative margins should be used at **your own risk**.

My recommendation is to give up on the negative top margin because it's, let's say, *problematic*, and use instead some shifting with `position: relative` (or don't shift at all).

Ref.:
https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#float-position
https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/box.html#margin-properties

Comment: [Floats](https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS2/visuren.html#floats) explicitly notes "floats with zero outer height or negative outer height do not shorten line boxes". Somewhat analogous to what happens with multiple floats.

Comment: Thank you, that makes a lot of sense. I'll refine the question title and body explicitly stating `negative margin` for future reference.