# mozaic grid with css

Tags: css, grid, masonry, mosaic

Trying to make a responsive mozaic grid, which has to look like this.
[target grid mosaic](https://i.stack.imgur.com/75H9E.jpg)

```
<div class="masonry grid clearfix">
        <div class="grid-item dbl-height"></div>
        <div class="grid-item mrg-on-left"></div>
        <div class="grid-item mrg-on-left dbl-width"></div>
        <div class="grid-item mrg-on-left mrg-on-top dbl-width middle-one"></div>
        <div class="grid-item mrg-on-left mrg-on-top dbl-height"></div>
        <div class="grid-item dbl-width pull-up-one bot-one"></div>
        <div class="grid-item mrg-on-left pull-up-one bot-one"></div>
</div>
```

and this is scss for this

```
    .grid {
    padding: 1px 0px;
}
.grid-item {
    padding-bottom: calc(((100% - 2px)/4));
    width: calc(((100% - 2px)/4));
    float: left;
    background: violet;
    &.dbl-height {
        padding-bottom: calc(((100% - 2px)/4)*2);
        &.right-one {
            padding-bottom: calc((((100% - 2px)/4)*2) - 1px);
        }
    }
    &.dbl-width {
        width: calc(((100% - 2px)/4)*2);
    }

    &.mrg-on-left {
        margin-left: 1px;
    }
    &.mrg-on-top {
        margin-top: 1px;
    }
    &.middle-one {
        padding-bottom: calc(((100% - 2px)/4) - 1px);
    }
    &.pull-up-one {
        margin-top: calc(((100% - 2px)/(-4)));
    }
    &.bot-one {
        padding-bottom: calc(((100% - 2px)/4) - 1px);
    }
}
```

If you look, the last two grid items have class 'bot-one'. I have made this floating and using 'padding-bottom' trick, to reach blocks with aspect ratio.

However can't reach the effect.... last 2 block are not stacking in right place... what is wrong here ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, see your last three block:

```
    <div class="grid-item mrg-on-left mrg-on-top dbl-height"></div>
    <div class="grid-item dbl-width pull-up-one bot-one"></div>
    <div class="grid-item mrg-on-left pull-up-one bot-one"></div>
```

According to spec, see rule 2(https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/visuren.html#float-rules):

> If the current box is left-floating, and there are any left-floating
>   boxes generated by elements earlier in the source document, then for
>   each such earlier box, either the left outer edge of the current box
>   must be to the right of the right outer edge of the earlier box, or
>   its top must be lower than the bottom of the earlier box. Analogous
>   rules hold for right-floating boxes.

Now, see the last three `div`s, your third-last block will let the element which behind it to place in the forth row.

The second-last `div` use `margin-top` to have a negative number which is same as its height(`padding-bottom`) and this cause it to out of flow(the forth row).

The last `div` can't get the right outer edge of second-last `div` so it use third-last and this cause it overlap the second-last `div`.

[image: overlap]
(black part is the last `div`)

A quick fix(add a margin bottom to the second-last element): https://jsfiddle.net/L0kove74/1/

Reference: [Negative margin breaks float](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35344103/negative-margin-breaks-float)

Comment: Thanks, you saved my day!

Comment: @LevonGrigoryan can you mark as solve or vote , thanks :D

Comment: I have marked, I need reputation, this to be visible